# Update with multiple joins in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, multiple-tables

I'm having a problem updating tables in a MySQL database (InnoDB).

I have three tables

1-`orders` Table

| orderId | userId | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 4 | bending |
| 8 | 4 | bending |

2- `orderedProducts`

| orderId | productId | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 22 | 1 |
| 7 | 24 | 1 |
| 8 | 22 | 2 |
| 8 | 20 | 1 |

3- `products`

| productId | quantity | purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 1 | 3 |
| 22 | 0 | 1 |
| 24 | 1 | 1 |

Ok now when I execute the following query:-

---

```
UPDATE 
    orders JOIN 
    orderedProduct ON orders.orderId=orderedProducts.orderedId JOIN 
    products ON products.productId=orderedProducts.productId
SET
    products.quantity=products.quantity+orderedProducts.quantity,
    products.purchased=products.purchased-orderedProducts.quantity,
    orders.status="canceled"
WHERE
    orders.userId=4;
```

---

Or this

---

```
UPDATE 
    orders, orderedProducts, products 
SET
    products.quantity=products.quantity+orderedProducts.quantity
    products.purchased=products.purchased-orderedProducts.quantity,
    orders.status="canceled"
WHERE
    orders.userId=4 AND products.productId=orderedProducts.productId;
```

---

I expected the result to be like this:-

**products**

| productId | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 2 |
| 22 | 3 |
| 24 | 2 |

But the result was as follows:-

| productId | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 2 |
| 22 | 1 |
| 24 | 2 |

Does anyone have any idea about what happened?

EDIT:-
The problem is solved. Thanks to every body i found the soluatiion from everyone's answer...

```
UPDATE 
    orders o JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            orderId , productId , SUM(quantity) as requiredQuantity 
            FROM 
                orderedProducts 
            GROUP BY 
                productId
    ) as op ON op.orderId=o.orderId JOIN
    products as p ON op.productId=p.productId
SET
    p.quantity=p.quantity+op.requiredQuantity,
    p.purchased=p.purchased-op.requiredQuantity,
    o.status="canceled"
WHERE
    o.userId=4;
```

Comment: *"Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times."* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem??

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any idea about what happened?

There are multiple rows in orderedProducts table for the same productId and so the result.

The following query shall give you the correct result as in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/9ZwZeLAL)

```
UPDATE products
SET quantity = quantity + (
  SELECT SUM(quantity)
  FROM orderedProducts
  WHERE productId = products.productId
  AND orderId IN (
    SELECT orderId
    FROM orders
    WHERE userId = 4
  )
);
```

Output :

`select * from products;`

| productId | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 2 |
| 22 | 3 |
| 24 | 2 |

Well, if you want to do the same using `join`;
You can do it as in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/2z5RUJs5):

```
    UPDATE products
JOIN (
    SELECT orderedProducts.productId, SUM(orderedProducts.quantity) AS total_quantity
    FROM orderedProducts
    JOIN orders ON orderedProducts.orderId = orders.orderId
    WHERE orders.userId = 4
    GROUP BY orderedProducts.productId
) AS ordered
ON products.productId = ordered.productId
SET products.quantity = products.quantity + ordered.total_quantity;
```

This also shall give the expected output

Update :

Based on your comment :

> In the Products table, there is another column that I want to modify
> (purchased). Also, in the Orders table, there is a column that I want
> to modify (status). I think in this case it is better to use JOIN, but
> it ignores the duplicate productId. Is there a specific formula that
> does not ignore duplicate values?

You can update it as below :

```
UPDATE products p
JOIN orderedProducts op ON p.productId = op.productId
JOIN orders o ON op.orderId = o.orderId
SET p.quantity = p.quantity + op.quantity,
p.purchased = p.purchased + op.quantity,
o.status = 'Processed'
WHERE o.userId = 4;
```

Comment: this works well, but in the question, I simplified the tables. In the Products table, there is another column that I want to modify (purchased). Also, in the Orders table, there is a column that I want to modify (status). I think in this case it is better to use JOIN, but it ignores the duplicate productId. Is there a specific formula that does not ignore duplicate values?

Comment: I have re-written the query using joins. Can you please check it now ?

Comment: Thank you, but there is still one problem. I can not modify the (status) column in orders table.

Comment: So, `o.status = 'Processed'``Can we remove from above query  along with presiding comma:

Or is there any restriction in updating `orders.status` column ?

Comment: sorry, i did not see last edit you made. Based on the latest modification, we will return to the same first problem. Duplicate values will be ignored when using (join).

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the updated quantity of every product :

```
select p.productId, sum(distinct p.quantity) + sum(op.quantity)
from products p
inner join orderedProducts op on op.productId = p.productId
inner join orders o on o.orderId = op.orderId
WHERE o.userId=4
group by p.productId
```

Using the previous query, the updated query could be as follows :

```
Update products p
inner join (
  select p.productId, sum(distinct p.quantity) + sum(op.quantity) as newQuantity
  from products p
  inner join orderedProducts op on op.productId = p.productId
  inner join orders o on o.orderId = op.orderId
  WHERE o.userId=4
  group by p.productId
) s on s.productId = p.productId
set quantity = s.newQuantity
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/0DEUtoBv)

Comment: This is not correct: `sum(p.quantity + op.quantity)`. You are adding `p.quantity` per order and only get the right result, because of "lucky" sample data.

Comment: Correct, thanks for your remarks :) I have updated my answer

Comment: sum(distinct .. ) will probably work, but it could also just be `p.quantity + sum(op.quantity)`. You might need to include `p.quantity` in the ORDER BY clause - But it's not needed in MySQL if `p.productId` is the PK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the question to be more clear about what I want..